# Connect JSP and Activity Workflow Engine

Tags: mysql, jsp, activiti

currently I am working with `JSP` and `Activity` Workflow Engine to Develop a Website.

In this project I would like to do these things:

- I have 3 roles: employee, boss, and back office
- Employee will submit a form from my website (developed by using JSP and MySQL), let says Form A
- When the form is submitted, then activity workflow engine will send an email to the employee and the boss
- Email to the employee contains some notification (says: the form is already submitted, etc)
- For the boss, the email will contains a link (link to the website) and said that there is one new form need to be reviewed
- After the boss clicked "Accept" or finish reviewing the form, then activiti workflow engine will send an email to the back office (contain link to the website and says 1 new form need to be proceed)
- Back office can either accept or reject
- After BO accept or reject, activiti will send an email again to the employee.

What I want to ask is: How can I do those process, I mean how can I connect the JSP and MySQL with Activity Workflow Engine?

Please help, I am new to JSP and Activiti Workflow Engine. Thanks so much.

Comment: you need to learn how to make web application web development jsp and mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is build a multilayer application. You can use Spring framework and Spring MVC. For presentation layer you can use JSP and in bussines layer you can handle Acitivit engine.